# compiling opencv with anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, opencv3.0

I'm trying to compile opencv3 with anaconda2 as my python interpreter on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/waspinator/opencv/install \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/waspinator/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.0.0 \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/waspinator/anaconda2/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

make -j4
```

but I get these errors repeated over and over again

```
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/bin/cmake: /home/waspinator/anaconda2/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
```

and after 10 minutes or so in the end I get this error:

```
make[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

is there an issue using opencv with anaconda, or am I doing something wrong with my approach?

Comment: I got the exact same problem following this guide to install caffe: 
https://gist.github.com/titipata/f0ef48ad2f0ebc07bcb9

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install anaconda on my Ubuntu machine and it took a while to get working. When I finally got it installed it messed up my OpenCV and I could never import it. If you are wanting to use the Spyder IDE (which is great and what I currently use) you can always use the command
`sudo apt-get install spyder3` in terminal or if you want the python 2.7 version use
`sudo apt-get install spyder`. After this you should be able to start it by going into your terminal and typing `spyder` or `spyder3`. If you are not a fan of using terminal it also can be opened in your Applications by hitting the menu button and typing in either Spyder or Spyder3.